# algorithm to find out if two sentence parts can be joined together

Tags: nlp, nltk

I'm looking to build an algorithm that can join together sentence parts. So, for example, it would know that

"drank it down and ordered a second glass,"

would be able to follow:

"He listened to what she had to say and ordered a glass of wine,"

but

"by trying to know what he could not understand,"

would not.

I'm familiar with the NLTK - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually proven to be unsolvable. The code would have to have understanding of the meaning of the words to be sure. What you are effectively asking for is a Context-free Grammar (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) which simply doesn't exist for human languages.

Comment: Correct, a rule based approach will work only very occasionally, but it might be possible to do it statistically. Create your own training data?